# UI-Router : Can I get always the same controller?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router to have some "menus" in my application.

```
$stateProvider.state("list"
    url: "/Focales"
    templateUrl: "/demo/focals.html"
    controller: FocalCtrl)
  $stateProvider.state("collection"
    url: "/Collections"
    templateUrl: "/demo/collections.html"
    controller: CollectionCtrl)
```

In my CollectionCtrl, I trigger a processing done on server and just waiting to display the information like this (CoffeeScript)

```
Progress = $resource('/collections/getProgress')

$scope.getProgress = () ->
    prg = Progress.get {}, ->
        $scope.currentProgress = prg
        $scope.getProgress() if prg.end isnt true
```

My issue : When the user moves to Focal and goes back to CollectionCtrl, I have a new instance of CollectionCtrl. So as far as I understand, the $scope.getProgress code still receives data but for the PREVIOUS CollectionCtrl (so the display is not updated...)

Is it possible to get the previous Controller rather than a new "instance" of the CollectionCtrl ? Why is a new CollectionCtrl created ?
What's the best approach: So I'm tempted to have a state data to store the current $scope so I could do $state.currentScope = prg rather than $scope.currentProgress = prg.
Is it a good approach ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach to take here is to define a [*service*](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services) which will communicate with the server and possibly cache the results. This service can be injected in the Controllers and the controllers can ask it for the *progress*, probably using `$watch`, though providing the service with a callback may also suffice, and update the UI based on that.

Controllers should be ephemeral and one should not rely on them being singleton-ish objects in Angular. Importantly, they should not contain any state apart from that needed by the template they are supporting. The are created again when the route becomes active so that we can write comparatively simpler code, initializing the `$scope` once and rest assured that it will contains as *fresh* information (w.r.t the route) for the template as possible. This also avoids memory leaks if a controller is kept around for each route like `/app/:object_id` and the user switches routes often.

Comment: Thanks ! The old controller seems still alive because it still receives events posted by the Server. When will it die ? How does Angular kill the controller ?

Comment: Angular will file a [`$destroy` event](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) on the scope when it is done with it (probably on _route change_) but javascript may still keep reference to it around. It'll be eventually garbage collected by the browser when the `Progress.get` function relinquishes it.