# Change included page and URL without re-initializing controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am making an application using AngularJS and want to be able to switch between "tabs" and swap back and forth different "partials" or html templates into a panel/container (using `ngInclude`).

Here's my template, which is wrapped inside a `ngView`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="list-group" data-fixed-sidebar data-nav-control>
            <a href="#/analyze/option1" class="list-group-item" data-tab-route="/analyze/option1.*" >Analyze Option 1</a>
            <a href="#/analyze/option2" class="list-group-item" data-tab-route="/analyze/option2.*">Analyze Option 2</a>
            <a href="#/analyze/option3" class="list-group-item" data-tab-route="/analyze/option3.*">Analyze Option 3</a>
            <a href="#/analyze/option4" class="list-group-item" data-tab-route="/analyze/option4.*">Analyze Option 4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div ng-include="child"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, when I click on one of the links (for example, the first link which routes to `#/analyze/option1`) it will reload my controller and lose track of it's current state. I am using `$route` and `$routeProvider` and would prefer a solution that keeps using this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are [meant to be ephemeral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893333/ui-router-can-i-get-always-the-same-controller). The correct way (TM), in my opinion, to do it would be to put the necessary state in [an `service`](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services), which is initialized in a singleton fashion and will retain state between route changes.